Prevent Dictionary Key from changing the case in the output
I have this code to generate the output shown below, when I debug the code, I can see the "CostLine.ExternalId" but when the result is shown in Postman, the case has changed to "costLine.ExternalId", Is there any way that we could prevent this?
Code:
rows[row.Id] = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
   {
      "CostLine.ExternalId", ["123456", "7959587", "8752296"]
   }
};

Result:
"rows": {
            "9335b339-d283-4175-bb4d-53f133fdee46": {
                "costLine.ExternalId": [
                    "123456"
                ]
            },
            "c557f6cc-b443-41ac-9214-601b3cb24326": {
                "costLine.ExternalId": [
                    "7959587", "8752296"
                ]
            }
        }

I have tried StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase but does not work. Any help is highly appreciated.

You didn't share some key information. We see a dictionary initialization, and then a fragment of a JSON document. Between the two there must be some serializer that is "smart" enough to apply some casing rule to the JSON object property names.

You are right, there is a code in Startup.cs which applies camel case for the controller outputs. I will see if I can override this setting. Thank you

Newtonsoft's JSON "NamingStrategy" property is "taking care" of camel-casing or not the object property names. Please see the following example:
Configure NamingStrategy property name serialization
With Microsoft JSON configuration it's a little bit different:
How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json
